# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in laravel 9

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-9

```
public function viewData($id){

        $result = Property::find($id);
        $view = view('home.property_detail',compact('result'))->render();
     return response()->json(['body'=>$view]);
    }
```

controller function

```
function view(id) {
        var route = "{{route('home.page')}}";
        $.get(route+'/view/details/'+ id, function (product) {
            $('#single_view').html('');
            $('#single_view').append(product.body);
            $('#view_model').modal('toggle');
        });
    }
```

function call on onclick
this function return "jquery.min.js:2          GET https://zehrii.com/view/details/24 500" error
click on this error show that title

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in resources/views/home/property_detail.blade.php

```php
@foreach (json_decode($result->features) as $feature)
<div class="col-sm-4">
    {{ $feature }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

It seems that {{ $feature }} is an object and you're trying to access it as a string, You need to call the individual property inside of the object, example:

```
$feature->title
```